# Feasible to run R + R Studio completely through Google Drive?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have unlimited Drive space that I've been using to sync files across my laptop and desktop through a local Drive folder (disregarding any connectivity/syncing issues that might arise).

I thought I would try and put R, R Studio, and everything associated with it on the drive too, but I think I've run into a minor problem. Both my computers have the same username, so the WD path is essentially the same. But I was trying to add `pacman` to my `.Rprofile` and found out some files (packages, Rstudio Git/SVN executables) are saved locally in documents or deep in appdata.

I feel like this is just the tip of the iceberg with problems that might arise with what I'm trying to do. Should I stop and keep everything separate or is there a straightforward way to get all of this to work nicely?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you're looking for a "container" e.g. docker http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/useR2015_docker.pdf

Comment: oh boy. that looks a little advanced. maybe i'll just keep it separate. are there any resources on how to keep a manageable and organized workspace over 2 separate computers?